# Is there anyway I can tally data using a GAS DataTable / PieChart?

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi Guys (I'm new to GAS),

I was wondering if it was possible to tally data in a dataTable and then display that tally appropriately using a pie chart.

To help illustrate what I am trying to do, below I have a dataTable describing people and the city, country and continent of the world they live in:

```
var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Name")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "City")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Country")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Continent")
.addRow(["Tom", "New York", "USA", "North America"])
.addRow(["Dick", "San Francisco", "USA", "North America"])
.addRow(["Harry", "San Francisco", "USA", "North America"])
.addRow(["Paul", "Los Angeles", "USA", "North America"])
.addRow(["Matt", "Sydney", "Australia", "Australia"])
.addRow(["John", "Melbourne", "Australia", "Australia"])
.addRow(["Craig", "London", "England", "Europe"])
.build();
```

I would like to be able to create a pie chart filtered by Country telling me what Cities people are from. I.e. the pie chart if filtered by Country "USA" should show slices of New York 25%, San Francisco 50%, Los Angeles 25%.

Is this even possible? The closest I have come is to create a "Tally" column in my dataTable (all assigned 1) so I can create the pie chart to begin with, I.e.:

```
var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Name")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "City")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Country")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Continent")
.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Tally")
.addRow(["Tom", "New York", "USA", "North America", 1])
.addRow(["Dick", "San Francisco", "USA", "North America", 1])
.addRow(["Harry", "San Francisco", "USA", "North America", 1])
.addRow(["Paul", "Los Angeles", "USA", "North America", 1])
.addRow(["Matt", "Sydney", "Australia", "Australia", 1])
.addRow(["John", "Melbourne", "Australia", "Australia", 1])
.addRow(["Craig", "London", "England", "Europe", 1])
.build();
```

But this then gives me a pie chart (again with the filter Country "USA") with the following slices - New York 25%, San Francisco 25%, San Francisco 25%, Los Angeles 25%. So still not entirely correct and it feels like a bit of a hack job.

The alternative I have thought of is to take the appropriate values from this table, perform my own calculations and create a 2nd (child if you will) dataTable that feeds the pie chart, but I don't think it's possible to read the values from an existing dataTable.

One question you may be asking at this point in time is, why don't I just have a dataTable consisting of only the data I need? - Well I'd like to create multiple charts / set multiple filters using this parent dataTable.

Another question may be - why don't you just create multiple, independent dataTables; one for each chart? If possible, I'd like to be able to use a set of filters that control the parent dataTable and then affect my calculations throughout the various pie charts I create.

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be appreciated. All the tutorials I've been through / examples I've found thus far are quite introductory and do not deal with this complexity. Please let me know if any of this does not make sense / if you need further info to diagnose.

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: Sorry, to add to this, I am writing all this using UIService. I'm assuming (from what I've read though) UIService is not advanced enough to handle any of this and I should be using HTMLService instead. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a bit of a noob, but for anybody out there who has asked this question, the way to go is in fact with the HTMLService. I guess Google have provided numerous tools to get the job done depending what you need to do - and HTMLService is the tool for anything complex.

I'm currently working on the solution, using dataTables and their pivot capabilities (more on that here - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Pivot). Once I've written some code, I'll add it up for all to see...